# Changing alt/ctrl + shift keys functionality

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys

I need to replace the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys combination with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, but I'm not sure how to do this. Also, for accessibility reasons I need to replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> with <kbd>RShift</kbd> key for example.

All I found is [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/) but unfortunately, it only replaces keys and not key combinations.

Is there any way of achieving this type of functionality?

Comment: You can use [AHK](http://autohotkey.com) for that. But if you want to press CAPSLOCK + another key and have it behave like ALT + SHIFT + another key, it might be more difficult than the simple hotkey.

Comment: @Vijay many thanks for your reply. Please add it as an answer in order to vote it.

Comment: @karel thanks for your input. Following Vijay answer, I've successfully replaced the key combination with CapsLock and RShift